# No funciona botón desplegable de Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando bootstrap para un botón desplegable, con las librerías de `Jquery` y la propia de bootstrap pero no se despliega.

```
<div id="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown">
           <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown link
           </a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

y al final del `body` tengo los scripts:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola ¿revisaste si tienes algun error en consola? de que no este llamando bien alguna libreria,

Te adjunto este ejemplo con bootstrap para que lo uses de referencia

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">                                         
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve este mismo error hace unos momentos.

Solo cambia `data-toggle="dropdown"` con `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`
y listo.

Puedes ver más información sobre esto en la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button).

Answer (score 0):

En general Bootstrap cambia los nombres de sus clases en las diferentes versiones, entonces puede que estés importando una versión diferente de Bootstrap que no corresponde con las clases que estás utilizando.

La versión la puedes verificar en todo momento en el vértice superior derecho de la página de Bootstrap.

Dejo un ejemplo funcional con la versión 5.2 (última a la fecha)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- CSS Bootstrap Versión 5.2 -->
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button
            class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Dropdown button
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- JS Bootstrap v5.2 -->
        <script
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Link a documentación de última versión.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

Link a Dropdowns:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/

Si deseas utilizar otra versión o ya tienes un proyecto con una versión anterior de Bootstrap solo debes seleccionar la versión correspondiente arriba a la derecha en la pagina de Bootstrap y luego encontrarás el o los CDN correcto junto con toda su documentación.

[image: Así se ve donde seleccionas la versión:]